# Wrap divs depends on their classes with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the next code:

```
<div class="components_container">
  <div class="first_group">Element 1</div>
  <div class="first_group">Element 2</div>
  <div class="first_group">Element 3</div>
  <div class="second_group">Element 4</div>
  <div class="second_group">Element 5</div>
  <div class="second_group">Element 6</div>
</div>
```

And I would like to wrap both groups in different div tags, like this:

```
<div class="components_container">
  <div class="group1">
    <div class="first_group">Element 1</div>
    <div class="first_group">Element 2</div>
    <div class="first_group">Element 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group2">
    <div class="second_group">Element 4</div>
    <div class="second_group">Element 5</div>
    <div class="second_group">Element 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. What have you tried to accomplish this? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you are trying to accomplish, you can do this in pure javascript:

Get a reference to the container (this code implies that you have only one element with that class):

```
var container = document.querySelector(".components_container");
```

Create the two external divs, add the classes and append them to the container:

```
var first_cont = document.createElement("div");
var second_cont = document.createElement("div");
first_cont.classList.add("group1");
second_cont.classList.add("group2");
container.appendChild(first_cont);
container.appendChild(second_cont);
```

Get the divs with a specific class and change their parent (remove child / append child):

```
var first_elements = container.querySelectorAll(".first_group");
var second_elements = container.querySelectorAll(".second_group");
for (el of first_elements) {
    container.removeChild(el);
    first_cont.appendChild(el);
}
for (el of second_elements) {
    container.removeChild(el);
    second_cont.appendChild(el);
}
```

This will do what you want, but please, next time try to add some more information, like some context, the steps that you tried or where are you finding difficulties :)